# Assembly, error while trying to push %ebp

Tags: assembly, x86

I have tried in this code, just to push %ebp register into the stack
but it seems to end in segmentation fault for some unknown reason the program just need to return 50

```
.section .data
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
call func ## fails here
movl $50,%ebx 
movl $1,%eax
int $0x80 ## terminate program

.type func,@function
func:
pushl %ebp 
ret
```

Comment: So why are you pushing something — anything onto the stack then? Usually you'll have to leave the stack the way you got it. The OS part or program that started your code expects the top of the stack unchanged and uses the %ebp value for something the next value on the stack was supposed to be used for.

Comment: When you call a function you should save the base pointer at the stack

Comment: @abba: Yes, that is one convention (not a rule), and if you push anything to the stack you have to restore the stack before returning from the function.

Comment: @Guffa, I get segmentation fault before i even have the chance to clean the stack

Comment: @abba: You are supposed to clean the stack inside the function. When you reach the `ret` the stack pointer has to be at the same place as when you entered the function.

Comment: The problem is obviously that you `push %ebp` and then the `ret` will try to use that as return address. Read about what `ret` does - it fetches the top of stack and goes there. Which is why you generally have to leave `esp` as it was upon entry, unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: Run your code in gdb and find out exactly where it fails. Folks here assume it fails at `ret`, but your comment indicates that it fails at 'call'. If it fails at `call`, then it is likely a stack overflow, although unlikely for such a small program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In func definition

```
    func:
    pushl %ebp 
    popl %ebp  ---> so ret instruction gets the right return address.    
    ret
```

you did not pop the ebp , so ret instruction returns to the address that is on the top of the  stack, which is ebp in this case and not the return address. 
This link could be helpful.  [Guide to assembly](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html)